# Linking Rows in SQL Based on Sorted Column Value

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-list, ranking

I have a database table that contains a list of "statuses" for donators.  People who have donated $5,000 have a certain rank, and the same for $10,000, $50,000, etc.  For the sake of convenience in various queries, I would like to have each status point to the next highest status (unless it is the highest).  Like so:

```
ID    Amount    Next ID
1     $5,000    2
2     $10,000   3
3     $50,000   Null
```

I would like to automatically update the Next ID column with a trigger, whenever a new row is inserted, or the Amount column edited during an update query, or a row is deleted.

I'm building this for Oracle 9i, so it's no problem to make a trigger that will do the updating--the only question is, how?

I'm struggling with the concept of doing a SELECT to get the whole table, with an ORDER BY on the Amount to sequence it, and then somehow using this to do the update.  It seems like it should be possible, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Also, I'm sure that some sort of PL/SQL loop might accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if 2 ppl donate the same amount?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos The amounts in the table are statuses, ranks, not donation figures for a given individual. Individuals would be assigned these ranks based on the dollar figure of their donation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Amount the PK

For example, the table is empty. Then the amount 10k is inserted:

```
Amount    Next ID
$10,000   null
```

Then the value 5k is inserted: find the first value > 5k, which is 10k, so use the 10k as the nextId:

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

Next, the value 7k is inserted: find the first value > 7k, which is 10k, so use 10k as the nextId:

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    10,000
$7,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

But now the value of 5k needs to be adjusted: find the max value < 7k and set the nextId as 7k:

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    7,000
$7,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

So, generalizing, the algorithm should be:

For any new value inserted:

1 - find the min value in the table > value being inserted and set the next id of the value being inserted as the min value in the table.

2 - find the max value in the table < value being inserted and set the next id of the max value in the table as the value being inserted.

### Deleting a row:

If the table is as this:

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    7,000
$7,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

and we want to delete the row 7,000 then

1 - Get the next id for the row being deleted. In this case it is 10k.

2 - Get the row with the next id 7k. In this case the row is the one with 5k.

3 - Set the row found in the step 2 with the next id found in the step 1.

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    10,000
$7,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

4 - Delete the row with 7k:

```
Amount    Next ID
$5,000    10,000
$10,000   null
```

Comment: Pretty good, but one thing that I realized is that deletion also needs to be taken into account.  What if a rank is deleted?

Comment: I figured out a different way of doing it, but yours is probably better.  ;)  Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that Alexandre's method would work well, but I am using a slightly different one.  I'm sure it's more expensive, but I feel safer with it.

This trigger will re-chain all of the statuses after any delete, insert, or update of the Amount column, using the same procedure in all scenarios:

```
create or replace trigger next_id_trg
  after
    delete or
    insert or
    update of AMOUNT
    on STATUS
  begin
    update STATUS
    set
      (STATUS.NEXT_ID) =
      (
        select
          NR.NEXT_ID
        from (
          with SQ as
            (
              select
                ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() over(order by STATUS.AMOUNT) as "ROW_NUMBER"
              from STATUS
            )
          select
            SQ1.ID,
            SQ2.ID as "NEXT_ID"
          from SQ SQ1
          left join SQ SQ2 on SQ2.ROW_NUMBER = SQ1.ROW_NUMBER + 1
        ) NR
        where STATUS.ID = NR.ID
      )
  end;
/
```

The basic points are:

1. Doing an update with a value from another table.
2. Using a subquery.
3. Using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in our subquery.
4. Naming the subquery using the "WITH" clause.
5. Joining the results of the subquery onto itself, using an increment on the ROW_NUMBER column.

This is paraphrased from my actual code, but I did test it and it does work just fine.  I'm sure that, given a large quantity of rows, there could be some more serious performance hit, because you will be filtering through every row in the table rather than just the modified ones, which is what is suggested by AlexandreSantos.  But I will have dozens in my table, so there's no problem there.

And frankly, this was fun to figure out, and I learned more about PL/SQL by doing this.  ^_^